# Open source project to ease the Assert part from the functional tests of .Net Core Web APIs

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, library, fluent-assertions

I have built an open-source project based on FluentAssertions in order to solve some recurring tasks I was doing while testing the .Net Core APIs I'm developing.

I find the capability of doing in memory end-to-end tests of the APIs I build a great addition in terms of productivity and validity.

With this project I want to solve two problems: to have a Assert API oriented for **HttpResponseMessage**, the type of response we get when we do an HTTP request with *HttpClient* and to get immediate feedback about what went wrong when the test fails, by providing the necessary details in the Test Explorer window from Visual Studio, so I can spend less time in debugging.

I choose FluentAssertions because it treats extensibility as a feature, so they have a great API for doing so. Also, they provide a mechanism to build your own failure messages and link them to a specific type, which is exactly what I needed.

The project is located [here](https://github.com/adrianiftode/FluentAssertions.Web/).

I have prepared a [branch](https://github.com/adrianiftode/FluentAssertions.Web/tree/code-review) for codereview.stackexchange.com to comply with the rule of not changing the code while you are reviewing it. Hopefully, this is OK, otherwise please let me know how I should proceed.

The nuget package built from this version is

```
Install-Package FluentAssertions.Web -Version 1.0.113
```

Next is an example of how  it can be used

```
using FluentAssertions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;
using Sample.Api.Net30.Controllers;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xunit;

namespace Sample.Api.Net30.Tests
{
    public class CommentsControllerTests : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
    {
        private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;

        public CommentsControllerTests(WebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
        {
            _factory = factory;
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task Get_Returns_Ok_With_CommentsList()
        {
            // Arrange
            var client = _factory.CreateClient();

            // Act
            var response = await client.GetAsync("/api/comments");

            // Assert
            response.Should().Be200Ok().And.BeAs(new[]
            {
                new { Author = "Adrian", Content = "Hey" },
                new { Author = "Johnny", Content = "Hey!" }
            });
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task Get_WithCommentId_Returns_Ok_With_The_Expected_Comment()
        {
            // Arrange
            var client = _factory.CreateClient();

            // Act
            var response = await client.GetAsync("/api/comments/1");

            // Assert
            response.Should().Be200Ok().And.BeAs(new
            {
                Author = "Adrian",
                Content = "Hey"
            });
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task Get_Returns_Ok_With_CommentsList_With_TwoUniqueComments()
        {
            // Arrange
            var client = _factory.CreateClient();

            // Act
            var response = await client.GetAsync("/api/comments");

            // Assert
            response.Should().Satisfy<IReadOnlyCollection<Comment>>(
                    model =>
                    {
                        model.Should().HaveCount(2);
                        model.Should().OnlyHaveUniqueItems(c => c.CommentId);
                    }
                );
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task Get_WithCommentId_Returns_A_NonSpam_Comment()
        {
            // Arrange
            var client = _factory.CreateClient();

            // Act
            var response = await client.GetAsync("/api/comments/1");

            // Assert
            response.Should().Satisfy(givenModelStructure: new
            {
                Author = default(string),
                Content = default(string)
            }, assertion: model =>
                {
                    model.Author.Should().NotBe("I DO SPAM!");
                    model.Content.Should().NotContain("BUY MORE");
                });
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task Get_WithCommentId_Returns_Response_That_Satisfies_Several_Assertions()
        {
            // Arrange
            var client = _factory.CreateClient();

            // Act
            var response = await client.GetAsync("/api/comments/1");

            // Assert
            response.Should().Satisfy(
                    r =>
                    {
                        r.Content.Headers.ContentRange.Should().BeNull();
                        r.Content.Headers.Allow.Should().NotBeNull();
                    }
            );
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task Post_ReturnsOk()
        {
            // Arrange
            var client = _factory.CreateClient();

            // Act
            var response = await client.PostAsync("/api/comments", new StringContent(@"{
                      ""author"": ""John"",
                      ""content"": ""Hey, you...""
                    }", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

            // Assert
            response.Should().Be200Ok();
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task Post_ReturnsOkAndWithContent()
        {
            // Arrange
            var client = _factory.CreateClient();

            // Act
            var response = await client.PostAsync("/api/comments", new StringContent(@"{
                      ""author"": ""John"",
                      ""content"": ""Hey, you...""
                    }", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

            // Assert
            response.Should().Be200Ok().And.BeAs(new
            {
                Author = "John",
                Content = "Hey, you..."
            });
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task Post_WithNoContent_ReturnsBadRequest()
        {
            // Arrange
            var client = _factory.CreateClient();

            // Act
            var response = await client.PostAsync("/api/comments", new StringContent("", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

            // Assert
            response.Should().Be400BadRequest()
                .And.HaveErrorMessage("*The input does not contain any JSON tokens*");
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task Post_WithNoAuthorAndNoContent_ReturnsBadRequest()
        {
            // Arrange
            var client = _factory.CreateClient();

            // Act
            var response = await client.PostAsync("/api/comments", new StringContent(@"{
                        ""author"": """",
                        ""content"": """"
                    }", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

            // Assert
            response.Should().Be400BadRequest()
                .And.HaveError("Author", "The Author field is required.")
                .And.HaveError("Content", "The Content field is required.");
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task Post_WithNoAuthor_ReturnsBadRequestWithUsefulMessage()
        {
            // Arrange
            var client = _factory.CreateClient();

            // Act
            var response = await client.PostAsync("/api/comments", new StringContent(@"{
                                          ""content"": ""Hey, you...""
                                        }", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

            // Assert
            response.Should().Be400BadRequest()
                .And.HaveError("Author", "The Author field is required.")
                .And.NotHaveError("content");
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task Post_WithNoAuthorButWithContent_ReturnsBadRequestWithAnErrorMessageRelatedToAuthorOnly()
        {
            // Arrange
            var client = _factory.CreateClient();

            // Act
            var response = await client.PostAsync("/api/comments", new StringContent(@"{
                                          ""content"": ""Hey, you...""
                                        }", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

            // Assert
            response.Should().Be400BadRequest()
                .And.OnlyHaveError("Author", "The Author field is required.");
        }
    }
}
```

And the controller that handles the HTTP requests and the corresponding model looks like:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Sample.Api.Net30.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CommentsController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Comment> Get() => new[]
        {
            new Comment { Author = "Adrian", Content = "Hey", CommentId = 1},
            new Comment { Author = "Johnny", Content = "Hey!", CommentId = 2 }
        };

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public Comment Get(int id) => new Comment { Author = "Adrian", Content = "Hey", CommentId = id };

        [HttpPost]
        public Comment Post([FromBody] Comment value) => value;
    }

    public class Comment
    {
        [Required]
        public string Author { get; set; }
        [Required, StringLength(maximumLength: 500)]
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public int CommentId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The assertion API aims to move the burden of remembering/typing the HTTP status codes as you have the option of recalling either the name or the number. Another common task is to deserialize the response to a certain model type and then to assert on.

The other feature is to show as much information as possible from the request-response pair, when a test fails. So in this example, for the following test, I will get the subsequent messages.

```
[Fact]
public async Task Get_Returns_Ok_With_CommentsList()
{
    // Arrange
    var client = _factory.CreateClient();

    // Act
    var response = await client.GetAsync("/api/comments");

    // Assert
    response.Should().Be200Ok().And.BeAs(new[]
    {
        new { Author = "Adrian", Content = "Hey" },
        new { Author = "Johnny", Content = "Hey!" },
        new { Author = "John", Content = "Hey!" }
    });
}
```

this test fails so the message is

```
Sample.Api.Net30.Tests.CommentsControllerTests.Get_Returns_Ok_With_CommentsList
       Source: CommentsControllerTests.cs line 22
       Duration: 128 ms

      Message: 
        Expected response to have a content equivalent to a model, but is has differences:

            - expected subjectModel to be a collection with 3 item(s), but {{ Author = Adrian, Content = Hey }, { Author = Johnny, Content = Hey! }}"
        "contains 1 item(s) less than"
        "{{ Author = Adrian, Content = Hey }, { Author = Johnny, Content = Hey! }, { Author = John, Content = Hey! }}.
        . 

        The HTTP response was:

        HTTP/1.1 200 OK
        Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
        Content-Length: 102

        [
            {
                "author": "Adrian",
                "content": "Hey",
                "commentId": 1
            },
            {
                "author": "Johnny",
                "content": "Hey!",
                "commentId": 2
            }
        ]
        The originated HTTP request was:

        GET http://localhost/api/comments HTTP 1.1
        Cookie: 
        Content-Length: 0


      Stack Trace: 
        XUnit2TestFramework.Throw(String message)
        TestFrameworkProvider.Throw(String message)
        DefaultAssertionStrategy.HandleFailure(String message)
        AssertionScope.FailWith(Func`1 failReasonFunc)
        AssertionScope.FailWith(Func`1 failReasonFunc)
        AssertionScope.FailWith(String message, Object[] args)
        HttpResponseMessageAssertions.BeAs[TModel](TModel expectedModel, String because, Object[] becauseArgs) line 52
        CommentsControllerTests.Get_Returns_Ok_With_CommentsList() line 31
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

This particular test uses `Be200Ok` and `BeAs<>` assertions. I will provide next the `BeAs` assertions to make a picture of how these are implemented

```
using FluentAssertions.Execution;
using FluentAssertions.Web.Internal;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace FluentAssertions.Web
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Contains a number of methods to assert that an <see cref="HttpResponseMessage"/> is in the expected state related to the HTTP content.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class HttpResponseMessageAssertions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Asserts that HTTP response content can be an equivalent representation of the expected model.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="expectedModel">
        /// The expected model.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="because">
        /// A formatted phrase as is supported by <see cref="string.Format(string,object[])" /> explaining why the assertion
        /// is needed. If the phrase does not start with the word <i>because</i>, it is prepended automatically.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="becauseArgs">
        /// Zero or more objects to format using the placeholders in <see paramref="because" />.
        /// </param>
        public AndConstraint<HttpResponseMessageAssertions> BeAs<TModel>(TModel expectedModel, string because = "", params object[] becauseArgs)
        {
            ExecuteSubjectNotNull(because, becauseArgs);

            if (expectedModel == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(expectedModel), "Cannot verify having a content equivalent to a model against a <null> model.");
            }

            var success = TryGetSubjectModel<TModel>(out var subjectModel);

            Execute.Assertion
                     .BecauseOf(because, becauseArgs)
                     .ForCondition(success)
                     .FailWith("Expected {context:response} to have a content equivalent to a model, but the JSON representation could not be parsed{reason}. {0}",
                         Subject);

            string[] failures;

            using (var scope = new AssertionScope())
            {
                subjectModel.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedModel);

                failures = scope.Discard();
            }

            Execute.Assertion
                       .BecauseOf(because, becauseArgs)
                       .ForCondition(failures.Length == 0)
                       .FailWith("Expected {context:response} to have a content equivalent to a model, but is has differences:{0}{reason}. {1}",
                           new AssertionsFailures(failures),
                           Subject);

            return new AndConstraint<HttpResponseMessageAssertions>(this);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Asserts that HTTP response has content that matches a wildcard pattern.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="expectedWildcardText">
        /// The wildcard pattern with which the subject is matched, where * and ? have special meanings.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="because">
        /// A formatted phrase as is supported by <see cref="string.Format(string,object[])" /> explaining why the assertion
        /// is needed. If the phrase does not start with the word <i>because</i>, it is prepended automatically.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="becauseArgs">
        /// Zero or more objects to format using the placeholders in <see paramref="because" />.
        /// </param>
        public AndConstraint<HttpResponseMessageAssertions> MatchInContent(string expectedWildcardText, string because = "", params object[] becauseArgs)
        {
            Guard.ThrowIfArgumentIsNull(expectedWildcardText, nameof(expectedWildcardText), "Cannot verify a HTTP response content match a <null> wildcard pattern.");
            ExecuteSubjectNotNull(because, becauseArgs);

            var content = GetContent();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
            {
                Execute.Assertion
                    .BecauseOf(because, becauseArgs)
                    .FailWith("Expected {context:response} to match the wildcard pattern {0} in its content, but content was <null>{reason}. {1}",
                        expectedWildcardText,
                        Subject);
            }

            string[] failures;

            using (var scope = new AssertionScope())
            {
                content.Should().Match(expectedWildcardText);

                failures = scope.Discard();
            }

            Execute.Assertion
                       .BecauseOf(because, becauseArgs)
                       .ForCondition(failures.Length == 0)
                       .FailWith("Expected {context:response} to match a wildcard pattern in its content, but does not since:{0}{reason}. {1}",
                           new AssertionsFailures(failures),
                           Subject);

            return new AndConstraint<HttpResponseMessageAssertions>(this);
        }
    }
}
```

In order to tell FluentAssertions how to display failure messages, you can implement the `IValueFormatter` so I have one for `HttpResponseMessage`

```
using FluentAssertions.Formatting;
using FluentAssertions.Web.Internal;
using FluentAssertions.Web.Internal.ContentProcessors;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FluentAssertions.Web
{
    internal class HttpResponseMessageFormatter : IValueFormatter
    {
        public bool CanHandle(object value) => value is HttpResponseMessage;

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public string Format(object value, FormattingContext context, FormatChild formatChild)
        {
            var response = (HttpResponseMessage)value;

            var messageBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            messageBuilder.AppendLine();
            messageBuilder.AppendLine();
            messageBuilder.AppendLine("The HTTP response was:");

            Func<Task> contentResolver = async () => await AppendHttpResponseMessage(messageBuilder, response);
            contentResolver.ExecuteInDefaultSynchronizationContext().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            return messageBuilder.ToString();
        }

        private static async Task AppendHttpResponseMessage(StringBuilder messageBuilder, HttpResponseMessage response)
        {
            await AppendResponse(messageBuilder, response);
            await AppendRequest(messageBuilder, response);
        }

        private static async Task AppendResponse(StringBuilder messageBuilder, HttpResponseMessage response)
        {
            AppendProtocolAndStatusCode(messageBuilder, response);
            Appender.AppendHeaders(messageBuilder, response.GetHeaders());
            AppendContentLength(messageBuilder, response);
            await AppendResponseContent(messageBuilder, response);
        }

        private static async Task AppendRequest(StringBuilder messageBuilder, HttpResponseMessage response)
        {
            var request = response.RequestMessage;
            messageBuilder.AppendLine();
            if (request == null)
            {
                messageBuilder.AppendLine("The originated HTTP request was <null>.");
                return;
            }
            messageBuilder.AppendLine("The originated HTTP request was:");
            messageBuilder.AppendLine();

            messageBuilder.AppendLine($"{request.Method.ToString().ToUpper()} {request.RequestUri} HTTP {request.Version}");

            Appender.AppendHeaders(messageBuilder, request.GetHeaders());
            AppendContentLength(messageBuilder, request);

            messageBuilder.AppendLine();

            await AppendRequestContent(messageBuilder, request.Content);
        }

        private static async Task AppendResponseContent(StringBuilder messageBuilder, HttpResponseMessage response)
        {
            var content = response.Content;
            if (content == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var processors = new List<IContentProcessor>();
            processors.Add(new InternalServerErrorProcessor(response, content));
            processors.AddRange(ProcessorsRunner.CommonProcessors(content));

            var contentBuilder = await ProcessorsRunner.RunProcessors(processors);
            messageBuilder.AppendLine();
            messageBuilder.Append(contentBuilder);
        }

        private static async Task AppendRequestContent(StringBuilder messageBuilder, HttpContent content)
        {
            await Appender.AppendContent(messageBuilder, content);
        }


        private static void AppendProtocolAndStatusCode(StringBuilder messageBuilder, HttpResponseMessage response)
        {
            messageBuilder.AppendLine();
            messageBuilder.AppendLine($@"HTTP/{response.Version} {(int)response.StatusCode} {response.StatusCode}");
        }

        private static void AppendContentLength(StringBuilder messageBuilder, HttpResponseMessage response)
        {
            if (!response.GetHeaders().Any(c => string.Equals(c.Key, "Content-Length", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
            {
                messageBuilder.AppendLine($"Content-Length: {response.Content?.Headers.ContentLength ?? 0}");
            }
        }

        private static void AppendContentLength(StringBuilder messageBuilder, HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            if (!request.GetHeaders()
                .Any(c => string.Equals(c.Key, "Content-Length", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            )
            {
                request.Content.TryGetContentLength(out long contentLength);
                messageBuilder.AppendLine($"Content-Length: {contentLength}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This class and its collaborators have increased complexity and unfortunately, fewer unit tests. Thus this is also a source of pain points lately, so I will have at some moment to invest more in this regard. The collaborators are some classes that have the knowledge of building failure messages based on certain predicates, like the `HttpContent` type and/or other aspects of the subjected `HttpResponse`. So for example for a JSON it will print it and beautify it, for a binary type like data, just an informative error message and for the an internal server error it will try to parse the stack trace embedded in the developer page. Next is the `JsonProcessor`.

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FluentAssertions.Web.Internal.ContentProcessors
{
    internal class JsonProcessor : ProcessorBase
    {
        private readonly HttpContent _httpContent;
        public JsonProcessor(HttpContent httpContent)
        {
            _httpContent = httpContent;
        }

        protected override async Task Handle(StringBuilder contentBuilder)
        {
            var content = await _httpContent.SafeReadAsStringAsync();

            var beautified = content?.BeautifyJson();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(beautified))
            {
                contentBuilder.Append(beautified);
            }
        }

        protected override bool CanHandle()
        {
            if (_httpContent == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            _httpContent.TryGetContentLength(out long length);
            var mediaType = _httpContent.Headers.ContentType?.MediaType;
            return length <= ContentFormatterOptions.MaximumReadableBytes
                   && (mediaType.EqualsCaseInsensitive("application/json") || mediaType.EqualsCaseInsensitive("application/problem+json"));
        }
    }
}
```

I feel at this moment that I'm close to a first production release, but I didn't get yet through a code review, to see what others think about this tool, so I kindly ask you to help me out.

So there would be some of my questions:

- How complete do you find the assertion API, does the current one fit 
  the day-to-day work? Do you have more suggestions?
- I focused on    writing quality code and went also with some of the
  C# 8.0 features. I most likely missed some aspects, please point them
- Do the samples fulfill their purpose?
- Is the documentation relevant? Are the unit tests complete, beyond
  code coverage?
- Any other aspects like CI/CD, automated builds, nuget releases?

Comment: The fact that nobody has written an answer yet seems to be a big compliment :D

Answer (score 2):

I created a very similar extension to `FluentAssertions` a while ago, which i have now abandoned. Here are my thoughts:

`Be400BadRequest`

There is no question what is asserted here, but on the other hand it might get tedious and repetitive to include both the status code and status name in the method. It is just a handful of status codes that are commonly used, so ommitting the number should be OK. An alternative could be `HaveStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)` which is also more correct (a response **has** a status but **is not** a status).

Moreover, you can add additional convenience assertions such as

```
    response.Should().HaveServerErrorStatusCode();
    response.Should().HaveRedirectionStatusCode();
    response.Should().HaveClientErrorStatusCode();
    response.Should().HaveSuccessStatusCode();
```

`BeAs`

I think `HaveContent` makes more sense, because again, a response might **have** a content/body but **is not** a content/body.
You can also do more around content assertions, like the ability to selectively assert it. For example:

```
    response.Should().HaveContentWithProperty<CustomerModel>(x => x.Name, "expectedname");
```

A general tip, about chaining. Since users can chain the assertions in any way, it is important to really think about as many common chaining use cases as possible, and verify that those make sense.

About using language features of c#, Visual Studio (plus plugins) can provide code suggestions in a much more effective way than i can do here manually.

Here is my project, for reference:

https://github.com/balanikas/FluentAssertions.Http
https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentAssertions.Http/1.0.0-beta1

Comment: Thank you, I know about your project, I learned about it when I researched what already exists. The reason I went with BeXXX is just that when people talk about HTTP requests they usually say "this request is a bad request because of this content".  There is also a HaveHttpStatus and NotHaveHttpStatus btw, among other Have extensions (HaveHeader, HaveError when there is a bad request etc).